# assoc & ftype stops working on Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, file-association, windows-11

In Win 10 I successfully associated `.lyx` files to launch `LyX` using a specific `userdir` with the following in `cmd` as admin:

```
assoc .lyx=LyX.Document 
ftype lyx.document="C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\bin\LyX.exe" -userdir A:\LyX "%1"
```

In Win 11 I installed LyX for just myself, and then tried

```
assoc .lyx=LyX.Document 
ftype lyx.document="C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\LyX 2.3\bin\LyX.exe" -userdir A:\LyX "%1"
```

This doesn't work at all to open `.lyx` files with that `userdir`.

However, I pinned `LyX` to the Win 11 taskbar and changed the "Target" to

```
"C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\LyX 2.3\bin\LyX.exe" -userdir A:\LyX
```

and "Start in" to

```
C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\LyX 2.3\bin"
```

And that launches `LyX` from the taskbar with the right userdir.

Does anyone know what is the reason for this, and how, in Win 11, I can set `.lyx` files to launch `LyX` using a specific `userdir`?